# Contenteditable: move one level up when having cursor in a textnode

Tags: javascript, html, range, contenteditable

How can I move the cursor to the top level of a contenteditable div when having it inside a textnode?

I need to have the cursor at the start of the line.

Thanks!

Comment: More information required. An example would be ideal.

Answer (score -1):

use this tag maybe it'll be help full.

```
vertical-align: top;
```